# how to create folder on BitBucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

How can I create a folder on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (web interface) to organize my repositories hierarchically?

Example :

```
https://bitbucket.org/my_account/my_folder/my_repository
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

BitBucket does not provide you with such a feature to add an folder and manage your repositories inside a folder. Once you are in an account you can keep adding repositories, but you cannot manage repositories inside your account in folders.

Comment: This answer was given when bitbucket did not have the feature.

Comment: Bitbucket still does not have this feature. The question is about, if we can create a folder within a Project, not within a repository.

Comment: Does now, see my post below.

Comment: Bitbucket lacks the feature that exists in Gitlab: Groups.  Groups is a useful way to organize a number of repositories so you can have the "product" repositories separate from the "devops" repositories, etc.

Comment: @ahmoreish You are creating a folder inside repo. The question is about creating a repo inside a folder.

Answer (score 25):

Figured it out,

Open Repo >> Goto Source >> + New File >> Under fileName:

folder1/folder2/file.extension

Comment: When I hit the + I see only Create Repository, Team, Project, and Snippet.

Comment: You cannot create a folder with multiple repos (though you can create a project). However once you create a repository you can create a file system that can act similarly. When creating a file you can specify it's directory path

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is possible to do this by following the above steps in the filename input box.

Answer (score 2):

Bitbucket has now Projects feature which enables to organize repositories hierarchically just as you describe. The URL does not reveal project, but in web you see them.

Comment: Unfortunately, projects is not the same like folders. You can't have a project inside other project. A project can contain only repositories, so it's only 1 step hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Go to source and click <kbd>Add File</kbd>. Then at the **filename**, first write the folder name, a slash (`/`), and the file name. E.g.,

```
folder/file.php
```

This will automatically create a new folder if one doesn't exist. This would be named with the `folder`, and the `file.php` will be inside of the folder.

```
Goto Source >> + New File >> Under fileName:

folder1/folder2/file.extension
```

Comment: This is not an answer for the actual question. The question was about organizing multiple repositories in folders and not creating files in one repository.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. It creates a folder no doubt, but the folder is created inside repository and will not show up in the URL of repository. Bitbucket supports only the Workspace>Project>Repository hiearchy in URL, folders not supported.

Answer (score -1):

I understand this is a bit of an old question but I would like to point out that Geeth W is actually wrong. You can in fact create folders in bitbucket, but the way that I've found to do it is via SourceTree.

1. Create your new branch
2. When specifying your new branch's name give it a folder prefixing the name, e.g. : backups/

When you finalize the branch creation you'll see in the UI that it is in a folder, and in the web panel you'll also see that it is a member of that folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that allows you to organize branches hierarchically, but not entire repos.

Answer (score -2):

go to source and click Add File then at the file name, firstly write the folder name slash the file name.

eg folder/file.php

this will automatically create a new folder if not existing which would be name as folder and the file.php would be inside the folder.

Answer (score -3):

You can link VScode to your repo and add folders there:

[image]

So bitbucket looks like...

[image]

Comment: I am unable to reproduce what version of bit bucket are required?

Comment: That's not what the OP is about.  Once you have a single repository, it's obvious how to create a directory hierarchy within it.  The problem is that Bitbucket lacks a feature that GitLab has.  The ability to organize multiple repositories together.  I.e. groups.

Comment: This is not the answer. You are creating a folder inside the repo. The question is about creating a folder in the path to the repo..... "https://bitbucket.org/my_account/my_folder/my_repository" . All other solutions provided here are creating folders inside repo. None of that answers the question where a folder name is required before repo name.